# Spring boot-JPA generate entity error from existing tables

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I generated entity class from a existing table made by DBA. columns in the table did not made by alphabetical order.
When I start my app, the following error message occured

--Error message--

Error executing DDL table name

There is already an object named table name in the database

--application.properties--

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false

is it possible to create entity class from existing table which columns were not made by alphabetical order?
and even if i set ddl-auto=none, my app tried to create new table?

---

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table sms.dbo.sms_data_test ()" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559) [hibernate-core-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504) [hibernate-core-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277) [hibernate-core-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71) [hibernate-core-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) [hibernate-core-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183) [hibernate-core-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) [hibernate-core-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310) [hibernate-core-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.__build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467) [hibernate-core-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:40008) [hibernate-core-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939) [hibernate-core-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.__createEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.1.0.RC2.jar:5.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:40002) [spring-orm-5.1.0.RC2.jar:5.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.__createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.1.0.RC2.jar:5.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:42002) [spring-orm-5.1.0.RC2.jar:5.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.1.0.RC2.jar:5.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.1.0.RC2.jar:5.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.1.0.RC2.jar:5.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802) [spring-beans-5.1.0.RC2.jar:5.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1739) [spring-beans-5.1.0.RC2.jar:5.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) [spring-beans-5.1.0.RC2.jar:5.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) [spring-beans-5.1.0.RC2.jar:5.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.0.RC2.jar:5.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RC2.jar:5.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.0.RC2.jar:5.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.0.RC2.jar:5.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.RC2.jar:5.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:855) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.RC2.jar:5.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.__refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.RC2.jar:5.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.jrLockAndRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:40002) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.RC2.jar:5.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:41008) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.RC2.jar:5.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.M2.jar:2.1.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:785) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.M2.jar:2.1.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:418) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.M2.jar:2.1.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:337) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.M2.jar:2.1.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1269) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.M2.jar:2.1.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1257) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.M2.jar:2.1.0.M2]
    at com.kr.dhl.EPassportApplication.main(EPassportApplication.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: There is already an object named 'sms_data_test' in the database.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217) ~[sqljdbc42-4.2.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1655) ~[sqljdbc42-4.2.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:885) ~[sqljdbc42-4.2.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:778) ~[sqljdbc42-4.2.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505) ~[sqljdbc42-4.2.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445) ~[sqljdbc42-4.2.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:191) ~[sqljdbc42-4.2.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:166) ~[sqljdbc42-4.2.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.execute(SQLServerStatement.java:751) ~[sqljdbc42-4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    ... 39 common frames omitted

--

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>webservice</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>webservice</name>
<description>webservice Java-SpringBoot version</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.M2</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc42</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>




</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <!-- ADDED FOR Querydsl -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

spring.jpa.database=sql-server

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

Best Regards,
JH

Comment: i) please format your question properly , ii) please post the error log as well iii) are you sure that the application.properties you posted are correct ? or its just a formatting problem

Answer (score 2):

Just have only `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` should work and it will not create table as this can have values like create, update, none etc, none mean nothing to do auto update /create/drop

And that is fine if you don’t have alphabetically as long as it’s matches with your entity.

**UPDATE**

STEP1:  Remove mysql connector if you are not using multiple data source

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

STEP 2: Add below properties to connect with MS SQL.(replace your db, user, pass, port)

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=springbootdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=Projects@123
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
```

Comment: thanks for your post.
even if i have spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none, my app tried to make creating table.
i also generated entity table from eclipse tool. still not sure what's wrong.

Comment: and do you have any Datasource config which overriding properties??

Comment: Removing spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false is not working.
and no other datasource config exists

Comment: Also all compete spring properties you have defined

Comment: After I imported the same code source from new STS, it is working well.
I'm not sure what' wrong but i guess that  something intruppeted in IDE.
thanks for your advices and hints. 
have a great weekends :)